# Passing a list of argument sets to a function

Tags: python, list, function

I've made a little progress on my understanding since submitting the poorly posed question below. I've gotten as far as this:

```
from collections import namedtuple
a = 3
Data = namedtuple('Data', 'b c')
d1 = Data(4,5)
d2 = Data(6,7)
data_list = (d1, d2)
def test1(a, *data) :
...
```

But *data is clearly not the correct syntax I seek for passing data_list.
How do I structure this so the function knows that this is a namedtuple list, defined as Data.

In the function, I need to do something like:
        print 'A = ', a
        for each in data
            print 'BC = ', data.b + data.c

---

Original question below.

I'm an old hand at C, but new to Python, so my perspective is likely misaligned.
I need to call a function with a couple of variables, and a list of a predefined set of values.
I imagine something like this:

```
class TestData
    def __init__(self, input, delay, result)
    self.input = input
    self.delay = delay
    self.result = result

#                (input, delay, result)
TestData list = [
                 (11, 250, 42)
                 (22, 500, 123)
                 (37, 100, 97)
                ]

RunTest(id, channel, list)
    setup(id, channel)
    for each in list
        ...
```

Can this work?
Or am I headed in the wrong direction?

Please excuse me if I haven't entered the example code with the correct formatting.

Comment: Do you want to create an object for each set of data items?

Comment: Well, have you tried it out? maybe it won't throw any exception, maybe it will, and then you can put it here as well

Comment: You'll get lots of syntax errors. Unless this should be considered as pseudo-code.

Comment: Heh. Stop trying g to type your variables :)

Comment: "How do I structure this so the function knows that this is a namedtuple list, defined as Data." you don't, python variables aren't typed. You just pass the function a list.

Answer (score 4):

**Setup**

```
class TestData:
     def __init__(self, inp, delay, result):
         self.input = inp
         self.delay = delay
         self.result = result

_list = [
  (11, 250, 42),
  (22, 500, 123),
  (37, 100, 97)
 ]
```

---

Use a *list comprehension* to create your objects, passing data at each iteration to the constructor:

```
>>> [TestData(*x) for x in _list]
[<__main__.TestData at 0x140b47eb8>,
 <__main__.TestData at 0x140b472b0>,
 <__main__.TestData at 0x140b474e0>]
```

Or, in a similar fashion, using a `for` loop:

```
>>> o_list = []
>>> for x in _list:
...    o_list.append(TestData(*x))
...
>>> o_list
[<__main__.TestData at 0x143d8a1d0>,
 <__main__.TestData at 0x143d8a2b0>,
 <__main__.TestData at 0x143d8a278>]
```

Comment: Wow! What a fast response.

Comment: I don't know whether a class is needed or is the best solution. I need the function to use a couple of values and run a loop operating on a list of values sets, with an arbitrary number of sets. The values in the set must have defined names so the function can access them correctly. The calling module must be able to create the lists in a simple way that assures the right values go to the right names. I might later generate the data sets and function calls from spreadsheet data.

Comment: @NorseMN If you just want to store data to pass to functions, a class isn't necessary. There are good enough structures to do that - lists, tuples, dictionaries, and so on. I suppose you're mapping structs to classes here - that's not required here unless you really need OOP based concepts here.

Comment: Yes. I'd love to have a solid structure. I want the called function to access values by name. I want the calling module to know the order of the names, but just initialize the lists in as simple a manner as practical. Named tuples and dictionaries don't seem to me to be an elegant way to initialize the values in each set.

Comment: @NorseMN If all you need are containers, imo named tuples would seem like fantastic candidates. But that's just me. Really it depends on what you're trying to do. But from what I understand, classes are really unnecessary overhead here.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a number of problems with the code you posted, I think you have more issues than just how to pass a list of values to a function.

Your `TestData` class looks perfectly fine, but this code won't work:

```
TestData list = [
                 (11, 250, 42)
                 (22, 500, 123)
                 (37, 100, 97)
                ]
```

If you're trying to create a new instance of `TestData`, you'd want:

```
list = TestData(
    (11, 250, 42),
    (22, 500, 123),
    (37, 100, 97)
    )
```

A couple notes here:

1. You probably don't want to call a local variable `list` since that'll clash with the `list()` global `list` class.
2. You're not passing a list of arguments to the `TestData` constructor, you're sending 3 separate arguments, each of which is a `tuple`.
3. Tuples are basically immutable lists (you can't reassign values in a tupe, you can't resize a tuple), and are constructed with `(a,b)` whereas lists are constructed with `[a,b]`

Next is this code:

```
RunTest(id, channel, list)
    setup(id, channel)
    for each in list
```

What is `RunTest` supposed to be? a function? a class? If it's a function, you'd want:

```
def RunTest(id, channel, list):
```

Note the leading `def` to define a function and the trailing `:` to start a new block of code. It's also python convention that only classes use `CammelCase`, functions should use `snake_case`.

What does your `setup` function look like? You don't give it here.

The code `for each in list` needs a trailing colon and you shouldn't use `each`, it's not necessary for a python for loop. The identifier in that position will have the element from each iteration over `list`. You probably want something like:

```
for item in list:
    do_something(item)
```

But that's also assuming that `list` is an iterable. If you really wanted `list` to be an instance of your `TestData` class, it's likely not iterable. Did you want to loop over each item from `list.input`?

Comment: OP is aware that this is all invalid code, it was representative pseudocode meant to demonstrate their point. Your answer, while well written out, is mostly superfluous.

Comment: I agree that what I posted is garbage and I should have identified it as pseudo code. I'll use "set" and "group" in the following question, to (try to) avoid specific Python terms.

Comment: What's the best way to define a set of named values, make a group of sets, pass it to a function that accesses the values of each set in a loop, by name? In addition, I need to define many such groups in a separate file with a call to the function for each group. Tuples don't appeal to me because the called function would have to use subscripts which are less readable. Enumerated names for the subscripts might help. But I hope that Python has more elegant solutions. Other options such as dictionaries appear equally awkward to me. It looks like a class, with named elements might be best.

Answer (score 0):

It can work, but not like that.

```
tdparams = [ ... ]

 ...

tdseq = [TestData(*params) for params in tdparams]
```

Comment: It's probably worth showing the full for-loop equivalent